# C Pointer Processing (basics)

Tags: c, pointers

I'm still struggling to get comfortable with pointers.  Not the concept - I understand memory locations, pointer increments matching variable length, etc - it's the syntax.  Here's an example that I think is one reason I get confused/can't get an intuitive grip on it:

```
int a = 42;
```

Allocates and puts 42 in an int-sized memory space

```
int *pa = &a;
```

Allocates a pointer in memory that points to the address containing the variable "a".

```
printf("%d \n", *pa);
```

Prints 42.

Simple/basic.  What bothers me is that:

```
int *pa = &a;
```

Would seem to indicate that `*pa` and `&a` are **equal**; equal to the memory address of `a`.  But in:

```
printf("%d \n", *pa);
```

`*pa` is the contents of the address `pa` points to.  So `*pa` appears to be two different things (address or int) depending on context.  And makes me concerned that "=" != "=".

Now I'm not trying to complain about/redefine/question the language, I'm just wondering if anyone has any tips that will help me understand this better, make it make more intuitive sense.  I assume it makes perfect logical sense if you really know the language; I'm hoping someone can explain it so it seems logical to me, too.

Comment: "points to the address"? Better "points to object a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make more intuitive sense if you used a syntax that explicitly shows `pa` as a variable with a different *type* than `a`.  This can be accomplished with simple spacing:

```
int a = 42;
int* pa = &a;
printf("%d", *pa);
```

Note that all I've done here is shifted the spacing in the declaration of `pa` so that the `*` is attached to its type rather than the variable itself.

Mind you, I do think that the syntax can be construed as confusing - it wouldn't be the first confusing thing about C.  Personally I might have preferred the use of something like `!` for dereferencing:

```
int a = 42;
int* pa = &a;
printf ("%d", !pa);  /* this is fantasy C */
```

Of course, then you'd have to come up with something else for logical not...

Comment: Great answer - exactly the sort of help I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

`int *` is not the same as the `*` in `printf("%d \n", *pa);`.

Specifically, `int *`, the entire thing, is basically a type: A "pointer to an `int`" type.

In other words, `int *` is a type.

However, invoking `*pa` means to **dereference** the pointer `pa`. So, `*` is an operator: the deference operator.

Also, to be pedantic, `=` is actually the assignment operator.

Three general cases for `*`:

1. Pointer type. `*` will follow a type. Example: `int *` is the pointer-to-an-int type.
2. Dereference operator. This is a **unary operator**, and dereferences a pointer to get the "underlying value" in the memory address.
3. Multiplication operator. This is a **binary operator**.

Comment: So * means at least 3 things depending on context.  

I know "=" is assignment and "==" is comparison.  However after an "=" assignment, the left and right sides should be the same value.  So I used "=" in my example since the statement I referenced used "=".

Comment: Yes. If * is with a type, then it means the entire thing is a type declaration. If there is no type and * is in front of a variable name, then it is the dereference operator (a **unary operator**). If * doesn't meet these two conditions and is used as a **binary operator**, then it is the multiplication operator.

Answer (score 2):

Your confusion seems to be because you initialize and declare the `pa` pointer at the same time, see this

```
int a = 42;
int *pa;

pa = &a;
```

now `*pa` and `&a` do not seem to be **equal**.

Comment: Yeah, the fact that the asterisk both means "pointer declaration" and "pointer dereference" in different contexts can be confusing.

Comment: @AlexisKing symbols mean different things in declarations than in expressions; you'll find the same thing with `[]`,  and with `&` if you ever learn C++

Comment: @MattMcNabb Of course, I'm intimately familiar with the semantics of those things. I just mean it could be confusing to a learner of the language.

Answer (score 2):

In C, there are 3 main uses of the `*` symbol. It takes place as part of a type, a unary operator, and an arithmetic operator.

The first case, as part of a type is used to initialize a pointer. `int* foo` means that foo is a pointer to an integer, that means foo holds the address of a pointer.
**Ex** `int* pa = &a`, *pa == address of a.*

The second case, as a unary operator is called the dereferencing operator. Unary is when the `*` has only a value on it's right. Like this it will act as a dereferencing operator. Dereferencing is expressing the value at a given address.
**Ex** *following from the previous example*
`pa = &a`
`if (*pa == 1)` *Look at what value is at the address p is holding*

The third case is trivial, but worth mentioning in how it differs from how it acts as a unary operator. As an arithmetic operator, it needs a value to the left and the right.
**Ex**`int x = 5 * 5`

**TL;DR** In `int *pa`, the `*` is part of the type, not the variable. It might be more clear to see it as `int* pa`. When it is not a part of a type, the `*` is a dereferencing operator, meaning to look at the value present at that address.

Comment: Appreciate the concise examples and nomenclature.